# SIM7600G how to send AT command when PID mode = 9018

Tags: linux

I'm trying to configure a SIM7600G USB module for my Raspberry PI 4.

I connected everything and used minicom to send AT command to change the PID to 9018, but I forgot to configure the APN (and pin settings) before exiting.
Now my SIM7600G is recognized as usb0 but I can't reconnect with minicom.

How can I send AT commands back to my module?

I hope somebody can help me.
Greetings to all

```
$ sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB2
minicom: ne peut ouvrir /dev/ttyUSB2: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```